# How do I open the new Start page with multitouch/pen input?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

When you mouse to the bottom left corner, you get the Start button. However when I do this with touch or pen input, nothing comes up. Is there some way to get back to the start menu without using a mouse/physical button? My tablet PC doesn't have a windows button mapped in Tablet mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slide your pen/finger from the right side of the screen to open a slide out menu which includes Start. Aside from a hardware key, this is how you can access the Start page from touch-only input.